# Definition of the Laplace Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, definition, laplace-transform

I'm studying from the book "Borel-Laplace Transform and Asymptotic Theory" by Sternin and Shatalov. At page 10, the authors provide the following definition of the Laplace Transform:
[image]

However, this definition isn't the same as the one I am used to, which reads as follows:

[image]

Is there any motivation or explanation of this? Thank you in advance.

*Edit:* The footnote 3 in the definition says

[image]

Comment: What does footnote 3 say on p.10 ?

Comment: The footnote says
"This is the definition of the [complex] Laplace transform, that is, the Laplace Transform of complex-analytic functions. The reader can see that for theta=0 formula (0.10) coincides with the usual Laplace transform (clearly, under the variable change y=1/x)". I still quite don't understand this election of variable change, I'll add this to the question, thank you!

Comment: Then the footnote 3 on page 10 solved the problem, Watson!

Comment: I mean, if I were to set the theta angle to zero I understand that we would (almost) recover the "typical" definition, however, why would it be natural to make the inversion y=1/x?

Comment: @the_candyman I think I understand now, but I would like to ask you in order to be sure: Is it possible that this variable change is due to the asymptotics interest in the source book? I think that could explain the 1/x

Comment: The authors confirm in that same footnote that they are doing the variable change to $y=1/x\,.$ *Why* they do it should be asked to them.

Comment: If you use $1/x$, the asymptotic expansions will be in positive powers of $x$ and be valid as $x\to 0$. With the other form, the expansions will be in positive powers of $1/s$ and be valid as $s\to \infty$. The authors chose to take the former. The rotation of the path of integration is for analytic continuation. This is essential when studying the Stokes phenomenon through the singularities of the Borel transfrom.